# Remove shipping block from magento admin order

Tags: orders, shipping-address, shipping-methods

How to remove shipping block from magento admin order.I have attached image also please have look.[image]

any help would be much appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shipping address is displayed from the template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml`.
this is the piece of code that does it (near the end of the file).

```
<?php if (!$this->getOrder()->getIsVirtual()): ?>
<div class="box-right">
    <!--Shipping Address-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-shipping-address"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address') ?></h4>
            <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getShippingAddress())?></div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you can create [your own theme for admin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) and copy the file `template/sales/order/view/info.phtml` to your theme and remove the code I added above.

This "shipping and handling" comes from the template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`.
The code is

```
<?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
    <div class="box-right">
        <!--Shipping Method-->
        <div class="entry-edit">
            <div class="entry-edit-head">
                <h4 class="icon-head head-shipping-method"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping &amp; Handling Information') ?></h4>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <?php  if ($_order->getTracksCollection()->count()) : ?>
                <a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>','trackorder','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>
                <br/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_order->getShippingDescription()): ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?></strong>

                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()): ?>
                        <?php $_excl = $this->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_excl = $this->displayPriceAttribute('shipping_amount', false, ' '); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $_incl = $this->displayShippingPriceInclTax($_order); ?>

                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('No shipping information available'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Do the same for this file as for the `info.phtml` file.